# How to get list of values stored in index?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, indexing

I'm having this issue in Oracle 11g R2. Table containing not null column which is indexed with non unique index. The index is not containing other columns.

Then I assumed that if I query distinct values of the column from the table, it would use index to get different values of the column (sounds logical to me). However at least explain plan is telling me it's doing full table scan. Also it took some time so probably the plan was not changed during run time. Optimizer index hint didn't helped.

I tried to search answer for this but no luck. Is there way to get values stored in index or somehow query the table without "touching" the table at all (like multi column index joins can)?

Thanks!

EDIT: This was about Oracle EBS gl_balances table and gl_balances_n2 index. I got answer and this changed the explain plan:

```
select /*+ index_ffs(gl gl_balances_n2) */
       distinct gl.period_name
  from gl_balances gl;
```

Comment: In general you assumptions are right. Can you post your select statement? How big is the table?

Comment: Try adding `your_column IS NOT NULL` condition to your query, this usually does the trick.

Comment: @YaroslavShabalin Shouldn't be required if the column is constrained to NOT NULL, as stated in the question.

Comment: @DavidAldridge Yes, but it fools CBO in some cases.

Comment: @YaroslavShabalin Never seen that happen. Would like to see a documented example of it, though.

Comment: I tried also "is not null" in where but no difference.

Comment: @DavidAldridge Ah, ok this works only if column is without `NOT NULL` constraint. Just checked it. If column is `NOT NULL` the plans are same, but if it is nullable then condition is useful. `create table t_test as select owner, object_name from all_objects;
create index t_test_ind1 on t_test(object_name);
select distinct t.object_name from T_TEST t;
select distinct t.object_name from T_TEST t where t.object_name is not null;
alter table t_test modify (object_name NULL);
select distinct t.object_name from T_TEST t;
select distinct t.object_name from T_TEST t where t.object_name is not null;`

Comment: You might want an order_by on that query, and for a very large result set that can change the execution plan. It doesn't sound like that would be the case here, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may not be more efficient to scan the index than to scan the table -- don't forget that the index segment also contains branch nodes, and each index entry has to contain a ROWID of about 16 bytes (if memory serves).

So a "fast full index scan", which is the plan you're looking to get, may not be as fast as a full table scan. (You'd use an index_ffs() hint for that, by the way.)

edit: It be possible to use a more exotic method

- Maintaining your own list by periodically querying the table using DBMS_Scheduler.
- A materialized view. Complete refresh on demand might be adequate, though barely better than just periodically querying the data and maintaining your own unique list.
- Making the index compressed, though that would only be of value for longish index keys.
- A bitmap index -- not for a concurrently modified table though.

Comment: You were right, thank you! The optimizer hint changed the plan but the result was equally slow :)